# change group Color of ExpendbleListView is not work good in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hello i use this code to change background of group when user click on it and group is collaps

```
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                if (!parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff9600"));
                } else  {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4fc1e9"));

                }
                if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    Toast.makeText(AdieActivity.this,String.valueOf( groupPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
```

when user click and group opne, the background color is changed but the problem is , some of the groups is not open but that backgrounds is change too

Comment: i think , i must write the code on the  @Override
    public View getGroupView
not in the expListView.setOnGroupClickListener
and it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overridden method is contained in my custom ExpandableListAdapter.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
    View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
     LinearLayout bevGroup = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.myid);

if(isExpanded)
{
    bevGroup.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.bgGroupBlack));
}
else
{
    bevGroup.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.bgTransparent));
}
}
```

Comment: i use the view in my class extends BaseExpandableListAdapter , and it work too 
 if (isExpanded) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.select);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.focuse);
        }